# Mailchimp Toggle display none / block

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

This might be a bit obscure, but I'm dealing with a group who is using a mailchimp campaign to reach a set of users. They want to be able to send users sets of articles, that can be toggled from display:none to display:block onclick. Article bodies start as display:none, and you click the article title to have them appear.

This is really easy to do using Jscript (obviously) but Mailchimp seems to strip all of the jscript out of my emails after we send them.

Anyone know of a way to add an undefined number of articles (could be anywhere from 5 to 65) to a mailchimp campaign, and to enable this sort of toggle functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's probably not a good idea to try sending JavaScript in email messages.  This is both for reasons of security... as well as practicality (as you don't know what browser or client an email recipient is going to be using.) [*(as discussed in this thread.)*](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=4622645)

But who knows... maybe the practicality of sending JavaScript in email will change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

All mail clients will strip out embedded scripts for security reasons.

Most will strip forms of CSS that may cause the email to break out of its container as well (things like `position`, `display` etc.). See: [Campaign Monitor CSS Guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Emails cannot be interactive other than including links, so the email can really only direct people to a web page that does what you want.